# WCF Entity Framework encrypt connection strings using web.config transforms

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, encryption

I am using .Net 4.5, VS2012, EF 6.0

I have the following web.config files in a wcf service solution:

```
web.config
web.DEV.config
web.Test.Config
web.UAT.config
web.Prod.config
```

The last 4 are web.config transformation files.

I know I can use aspnet_regiis -pef to encrypt the web.config and it works just fine.

How will I encrypt the transformation files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run aspnet_regiis -pef on the transformed web.config after it is published.

Comment: I understand that this works very well on my machine. But how will I make sure it works fine on other machines? How do I create a key that is common?

Comment: This link describes how you can share the encryption key between different servers: http://jimmylarkin.net/post/2013/04/09/Encrypting-NET-configuration-file.aspx